# How to add OpenShift MongoDB environment variables to my Java Application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, openshift

I have my MongoDB connection in my dispatcher servlet as follows.

```html
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
  <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
  <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="shop" />
</bean>
```

After I setup a MongoDB Cartridge in openshift i got connection credentials as follows.

MongoDB 2.4 database added.  Please make note of these credentials:

> Root User:    xxx
>   Root Password: yyy
>   Database Name: jbossews 
>   ConnectionURL:mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/

How can I insert these variables into my servlet so that the application uses the mongodb provided by openshift.